# Blender Stack Exchange now requires all users to be registered before posting

Tags: discussion, moderation, announcement

This is not really a question, more of community announcement.

Due to the recent spam wave that is currently affecting several sites of the Stack Exchange network, we decided to request that as of today all users are required to be registered before posting on Blender Stack Exchange.

That means anyone attempting to ask a question or post an answer must now go through the formal process of registering by creating an account and providing a valid email address.

This is in contrast to how it worked until now, where any users could post on our site or propose edits as guests, that is without a permanent registered account or providing a valid email address.

This will not affect any of the current users or existing accounts, nor how the site works, but will hopefully provide for a better experience in a few ways.

Will hopefully make it harder for spammers to intrude our community, and reduce the amount of unwanted posts. This is by no means a full proof solution, just a very basic first line of defense that should at the very least discourage the least persistent or the least technologically advanced of the attackers.

As discussed with other mods we believe allowing guest accounts never really served us well anyway, which also affected our decision independently of the spam issue at hand. It does lower the barrier for new users and "one-off" users who have no long term interest in Blender and want to just ask a single question and move on.

This however comes at the cost of moderation overhead with little benefits. Lots of users who posted as guests lost access to their accounts, preventing them from editing posts, improving their questions, provide more details or accept answers.

These users are also more likely to post low quality content with little future value, and less likely to get involved with the community and provide any meaningful long term value.

If anyone has any questions or concerns please voice them, and don't hesitate to reach out.

Comment: Imho it should always be the default behavior on any forum that wants a minimum of content quality and user involvement, regardless of spammers. Great decision.